# OpenGL in Ubuntu (C Language) saying things are undeclared

Tags: c, opengl, ubuntu, gcc, undeclared-identifier

So I just started learning OpenGL and I'm doing so Ubuntu with the C language.

I have done a few examples from my lecturers notes and they worked however this one is giving me errors.

```
callbackexample.c: In function ‘main’:
callbackexample.c:17:18: error: ‘displays’ undeclared (first use in this function)
callbackexample.c:17:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each     function it appears in
```

and so on for every method in my file.
I followed his notes word for word and I'm getting this so I'm not sure whats going wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define DEG_TO_RAD 0.017453

int singleb, doubleb;   //window ids
GLfloat theta = 0.0;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

glutInit(&argc, argv);

//create single buffered window
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
singleb = glutCreateWindow("single_buffered");
glutDisplayFunc(displays);
glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutKeyboardFunc(mykey);

//create double buffered window
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowPosition(400,0); //create window to the right
doubleb = glutCreateWindow("double_buffered");
glutDisplayFunc(displayd);
glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutCreateMenu(quit_menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("quit", 1);
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

glutMainLoop();
}


void displays() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f ( cos(DEG_TO_RAD * theta),
            sin(DEG_TO_RAD * theta));
    glVertex2f ( -sin(DEG_TO_RAD * theta),
            cos(DEG_TO_RAD * theta));
    glVertex2f ( -cos(DEG_TO_RAD * theta),
            -sin(DEG_TO_RAD * theta));
    glVertex2f ( sin(DEG_TO_RAD * theta),
            -cos(DEG_TO_RAD * theta));

glEnd();
glFlush();
}
```

This is just some code of the main method and the first method after it which I get an error on. By undeclared I guess it means that the methods aren't declared but I followed his code so I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use the `displays` method in the main function, before declaring it. You need to either move the entire function before the main function or add the stub to the top:

```
void displays();

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   ...
}

void displays(){
   ...
}
```

C parses everything in the order it sees it - you cannot use a method that hasn't been declared in its entirety, or at least had a declaration that it will exist at some point.

In regards to your comments:
The cannot find -l* stuff you are getting implies that you either haven't installed the development libraries for OpenGL or have them set up strangely - this is saying that it cannot find the library files to link against.

Additionally, the `mykey` problem implies that you either haven;t declared a `mykey` function or are not declaring it as per the prototype:

```
void mykey(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
```

Comment: Ah that worked thanks. I get another compile saying WARNING: passing argument 1 of glutKeyboardFunc from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Also it says it cannot find -lgl or -lglu when I compile using:

callbackexample.c -o callbackexample -lgl -lglu -lm -lX11

Comment: If it worked, consider accepting the answer. Also updated the answer for your additional problems.

Comment: yep did just there thanks :) how can i find -lgl and -lglu? I googled them and couldn't see anything about them

Also, in my lecturers notes he defines mykey as void mykey(int key) so I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it?

Comment: Just add those two `int x` and `int y` as parameters, which should make it match the prototype the `glutKeyboardFunc` is checking for. Alternativly, this could be a by product of the first problem - you may of may not have an old version of Glut on your system.

Comment: Yeah it fixed the key error anyway but I still get the -lgl and -lglu errors. I'm in ubuntu and when I tried update it said i have the newest versions of everything

Comment: -lgl and -lglu come from the graphics driver. If you use the closed-source Nvidia driver you should have them. If not you need to install the Mesa development packages.